# How does one format a path in order to take in a generic JSON object in Express.JS?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, express

Below is a generic use of Js, Node.js, and Express.js

```
app.get('/person', function(req, res, next){
 console.log(req.body);
}
```

I am sending the current curl command

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET -d '{"name":"me", "phone":"123"}' localhost:1337/persons
```

And my console.log() as I assumed would print {} an empty container. Now from reading the Express.js documentation I know I could arrange the URL to take in the parameters: /persons/:person/id/:id and make my JSON input valid, but what I want to know is if I can take any object JSON passed by a user? In other words, what if my json had an extra field; would this require an entirely new express handler? If this is not possible, is this due to security issues or is this just really poor design? Thanks

Comment: did my answer solve the issue?

Comment: super apologies for not getting back; wasn't available to test it out up until now! It did in fact work! I had everything else included, the only line I didn't already have was = app.use(bodyParser.json());. Thank you so much!

Comment: no worries. thanx & cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `man curl` says `-d` or `--data` adds the data into the body of the request.

> **-d, --data**
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server,
>   in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML
>   form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the
>   data to the server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F, --form.
>
> -d, --data is the same as --data-ascii. --data-raw is almost the same but does not have a special interpretation of the @ character. To post
>   data purely binary, you should instead use the --data-binary option.
>   To URL-encode the value of a form field you may use --data-urlencode.

So, you would need a package like `body-parser` to parse it.

install it like `npm install body-parser` and add these lines to your code and your issue will be solved.

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

*Note:*

*I'd recommend to use `-X POST` instead of `GET`  in your curl and `app.post()` in your code if you want to send a body payload.*

*Also please note typo: the curl is to `/persons` but the code has `app.get('/person',` correct either one of them.*